# FileSync local endpoint offline

Tags: azure, dns, azure-storage

I have 3 servers (one of them with Windows Server 2012 R2 and 2 with Windows Server 2019) and I use Azure FileSync to sync files between them.
Since a few days I have a problem, the 2012 R2 server is appearing offline in the azure portal (it shows "no activity"). I tried the `Test-StorageSyncNetworkConnectivity` cmdlet and it fails with the following message:

```
Discovery service connectivity result:
        Result: Success
        HostUri: unknown
        HostIPv4Addr: Fail. DNS name does not exist. Resolution through GetAddrInfo failed with error: 11001
        HostIPv6Addr: Fail. DNS name does not exist. Resolution through GetAddrInfo failed with error: 11001

Management service connectivity result:
        Result: Fail. Failed to run test
        HostUri: unknown
        HostIPv4Addr: Fail. DNS name does not exist. Resolution through GetAddrInfo failed with error: 11001
        HostIPv6Addr: Fail. DNS name does not exist. Resolution through GetAddrInfo failed with error: 11001
        HostNetworkLatency [min,avg,max]: Network Latency Request Failed.

Monitoring service connectivity result:
        Result: No response from monitoring agent process.
        HostUri: unknown
        HostIPsAddr: IPv4 and Ipv6 addresses do not exist

ServerEndpoint: faf66731-1e22-47eb-93eb-b8d3331f0de2
        SyncServiceResult:
        SyncServiceHostUri:
        SyncServiceHostIPsAddr: IPv4 and Ipv6 addresses do not exist
        SyncServiceHostNetworkLatency: Request Failed.


ServerEndpoint: 80f3bb96-463b-4f86-9e26-8dcf0c92f915
        SyncServiceResult:
        SyncServiceHostUri:
        SyncServiceHostIPsAddr: IPv4 and Ipv6 addresses do not exist
        SyncServiceHostNetworkLatency: Request Failed.


ServerEndpoint: b9a874b4-7acd-4174-b5e8-26ac23c84c7e
        SyncServiceResult:
        SyncServiceHostUri:
        SyncServiceHostIPsAddr: IPv4 and Ipv6 addresses do not exist
        SyncServiceHostNetworkLatency: Request Failed.


Remediation Steps
For Azure File Sync to work correctly, you will need to configure your servers to communicate with multiple Azure servic
es
Refer the following public document for details on proxy settings or firewall settings for Azure File Sync - https://aka
.ms/AFS/ProxyAndFirewall
If you have configured a private endpoint refer the following public document for configuring private endpoint for Azure
 File Sync - https://aka.ms/AFS/PrivateEndpoint



                                          NetworkTestPassed Report
                                          ----------------- ------
                                                      False ...
```

The problem seems to be DNS related, but I tried the `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName <remote-host> -Port 443` cmdlet with the correct URLs (taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-firewall-and-proxy#test-network-connectivity-to-service-endpoints) and all the endpoints seems to be working fine (the ping is failing but I think that is regular behavior. E.g.:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Azure\StorageSyncAgent> Test-NetConnection -ComputerName tm-kailani7.one.microsoft.com -Port 443
AVVISO: Ping to tm-kailani7.one.microsoft.com failed -- Status: TimedOut
ComputerName           : tm-kailani7.one.microsoft.com
RemoteAddress          : 20.38.85.153
RemotePort             : 443
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet 2
SourceAddress          : 192.168.0.185
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : True
```

I also tried the `FileSyncErrorsReport.ps1` but even that doesn't give me any error:

```
AVVISO: There are no file sync errors to report. Either the last completed sync session did not have per-item errors or
 the ItemResults event log on the server wrapped due to too many per-item errors and the event log no longer contains
errors for this sync group. To learn more, see the Azure File Sync troubleshooting documentation:
https://aka.ms/AFS/FileSyncErrorReport
```

I think the problem lies with the fact that the `AzureStorageSyncMonitor.exe` process is not running and if i try to run it manually it just closes itself after a few seconds.
I've got no event ID 9301 (specified here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-troubleshoot?tabs=portal1%2Cazure-portal#server-endpoint-health) and by searching in the other folder of eventvwr i could only find the event 4104 which shows me some error dated to the last time the server has reached the Azure endpoint:

```
Querying for new jobs failed.

HttpErrorCode: 0x80C8700C
InternalErrorCode: 0x80C80300
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

•   Kindly please **check the event ID 9302 in the ‘FileSync’ telemetry logs under ‘Application and Service Logs’ in the event viewer for the active sync sessions logged every 5 to 10 minutes and check whether it is making any progress as the ‘AzureStorageSyncMonitor.exe’ utility synchronizes the status of the Server endpoint to the storage sync service in the portal**.

•   You can also **check the ‘Perfmon.msc’, i.e., performance counter which is built-in to the Azure File Sync to monitor the sync activity locally on the server**.

•   Finally, please **check the Server’s configured IP address settings too as you are encountering the DNS resolution issue** while trying to **execute the ‘Test-StorageSyncNetworkConnectivity’ command**. In the **IP address settings, please check whether the configured DNS server IP addresses (Preferred and Secondary) are configured correct and are reachable**.

Also, **check the ‘localhosts’ file in the ‘C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc’ path whether it contains the correct IP address of the server, i.e., Windows Server 2012 R2 and its expected DNS hostname as various services on the server itself including the ‘AzureStorageSyncMonitor’ refer the ‘localhosts’ file for sending DNS requests to the connected/configured external services and for communicating between the internal services also**.

•   Finally, would suggest you to ***please disable negative caching on the DNS client, put the suffix with the matching host A record as the last entry in the suffix search list and use the ‘AF_UNSPEC’ for the family and let your code determine the ‘A/AAAA’ results for you***.

For more detailed information on this, kindly refer to the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/getaddrinfo-fails-error-11001-call-af-inet6-family#workaround***